# sails.js req.file.upload with bluebird promise

Tags: upload, promise, sails.js

I'm using sails.js as my backend with bluebird promise, I tried to upload file using req.file.upload, the callback way works just fine and the file gets uploaded:

```
req.file('file').upload({
    maxBytes: 2000000,
    dirname: 'uploadFolder'
}, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
    }
    return res.ok();
}
```

But the promise way does not:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fileUploader = Promise.promisify(req.file('file').upload);
fileUploader({
    maxBytes: 2000000,
    dirname: currentUploadFolder
}).then(function(files) {
    console.log(files);
    return Promise.resolve(files);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

File doesn't get uploaded and the console keeps complaining:

```
data:    app.js:1800 - [TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]
```

Any thoughts please?

Comment: What's on app.js:1800? I don't use promises directly, but i use them with fibers, so the promisified version of upload works ok for me. Is your .then getting called? Or it goes straight to the catch?

Comment: App.js 1800 is just some debug info and should be ignored I think, .then didn't get called, it goes straight to catch

Comment: Try `upstream.upload = Promise.promisify(upstream.upload)` where upstream is a reference to `req.file('file')`, so you'll call upload in context of the upstream, let me know if it works. I can't test right now so i don't wan't to create an answer yet.

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me, I wind up using the regular req.file.upload callback way, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This case is unique and you can't use `promisify` here. You need to create new Promise and return it.

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  req.file('file').upload({
    maxBytes: 2000000,
    dirname: 'uploadFolder'
  }, function (error, files) {
    return error ? reject(error) : resolve(files);
  }
});
```

You can move it to helper\services\whatever and got something like this

```
// api/services/UploadService.js
module.exports = {
  uploadFile: function(req) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      req.file('file').upload({
        maxBytes: 2000000,
        dirname: 'uploadFolder'
      }, function (error, files) {
        return error ? reject(error) : resolve(files);
      }
    });
  }
};

// api/controllers/AnyController.js
module.exports = {
  upload: function(req, res) {
    UploadService
      .uploadFile(req)
      .then(res.ok)
      .catch(res.negotiate);
  }
};
```

Comment: I think yours is a solution, but new promise seems like an anti pattern in my understanding? Anyway, I wind up just using callback, saves a lot of trouble, thanks anyway! Accepted as the answer.

Comment: No, it's not. Here you can read about promise anti-patterns - http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/. But really, creating your own Promise is not an anti-pattern.

Comment: @ghaiklor Can you test again?  I'm doing the same but the size of file limit about 100kb, weird

Comment: @trungducng pay attention to the documentation of Sails. I bet, they are changed interface for it.